# Loading a C struct from a file

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm reading some code which `mmap`s a file, and assigns the returned value to a pointer to a `struct`:

```
struct cache_header {
    unsigned int signature;
    unsigned int version;
    unsigned int entries;
    unsigned char sha1[20];
};

struct cache_header *hdr;
map = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
hdr = map;
```

Later the code `verifies` the struct loaded from the file, this is the part I don't understand:

```
SHA_CTX c;
    unsigned char sha1[20];
    if (hdr->signature != CACHE_SIGNATURE)
        return error("bad signature");
    if (hdr->version != 1)
        return error("bad version");
    SHA1_Init(&c);
    SHA1_Update(&c, hdr, offsetof(struct cache_header, sha1));
    SHA1_Update(&c, hdr+1, size - sizeof(*hdr));
    SHA1_Final(sha1, &c);
    if (memcmp(sha1, hdr->sha1, 20))
        return error("bad header sha1");
    return 0;
```

Can you explain why :

1.there's `hdr+1` in the second call to `SHA1_Update`

2.In the call to memcmp, `hdr->sha1`is a pointer, wouldn't it's value be invalid, since the struct has just been read from the disk, and it was written by another program of the codebase.

Note: `size` is the size of file

Comment: Is `hdr->sha1` not an array actually? Regarding `hdr+1`, that just creates a pointer to the next `struct cache_header`. Perhaps the file has several?

Comment: `hdr->sha1` is an *array*, not a pointer. It can *decay* to a pointer to its first element, but is in itself not a pointer.

Comment: As for the first question, you have to give us more context. More specifically please tell us what `size` is, and how it is initialized.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

1. Perhaps the file is large enough to contain two instances of the struct? What is the value of `size`?
2. No, `hdr->sha1` is not a pointer, it's an array. That array is part of the `struct`, and `hdr->sha1` evaluates to the address of the first element. There is no pointer stored there.

Also note that this is bad practice, since you're relying on the `structs` being packed (no padding) without making sure.

Comment: Isn't an array name in C just a pointer to the first element of the array?

Comment: @saga No, absolutely not. It *evaluates* to one at times, but it's not the same thing. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer) for more.